# Parameterised queries with table-valued parameters

Tags: sql, postgresql, jooq

How can I build a parameterised query/view/stored procedure in PostgreSQL (or, reluctantly, a function in Java) to support table-values parameters?

My current toolchain is PostgreSQL, JDBC and Java with the jooq library.

Some context.

I have a (in reality quite complicated) query that defines some aggregation processing of some statistical data. For the purposes of simplicity, let's assume it's of the form:

```
create view aggregated_data as
  select table1.c1, sum(table2.c2) 
  from table1 
  inner join table2 on table1.c1 = table2.c1
  group by table1.c1;
```

What I want to do is parameterise this definition such that I can pass 'table2' as a parameter, because I want that passed 'table2' to only contain rows based on other conditions.

More explicitly, I'm after something like:

```
create view aggregated_data(some_table_valued_parameter) as
  select table1.c1, sum(table2.c2) 
  from table1 
  inner join ( 
     select c1, c2 from some_table_valued_parameter
  ) table2 on table1.c1 = table2.c1
  group by table1.c1;
```

How can I define a **something** that lets me keep all the scaffolding and just pass in some_table_valued_parameter?

I'm considering some sort of stored procedure as my first option, although from what I understand PostgreSQL does not support table-values parameters, so it might not be possible.

A second option (which I am pretty sure would work) is to use JOOQ and a Java function to build a query dynamically. This is less preferable, though, because the database is meant to support people logging in at the console and typing SQL, and I'd like them to be able to benefit from the scaffolding, too.

Any hints or clues would be appreciated.

Comment: Quite interesting. Like you're trying to factor out of possibly many views the complicated query that contains the aggregation. As far as I can tell, you're only possibility with SQL92 would be to leave out aggregation and create a view with just the complicated query (plus the joining columns). For every possibly table2 you could join with that view AND aggregate.

Comment: I know of functions that return tables. But never heard of them taking tables as arguments.

Comment: Unless the 'some_table_valued_parameter' sub-query is more complicated than stated, you can simply join 'some_table_valued_parameter' to 'table1'.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It seems that your main problem is to have a table-valued parameter to your stored function, which indeed isn't supported in PostgreSQL. But you can use an array of record, which is essentially the same with a bit more boiler-plate (and perhaps some performance implications):

```
CREATE TYPE my_rec AS (
  c1 BIGINT,
  c2 BIGINT
);
```

And then:

```
CREATE FUNCTION my_func(almost_a_table my_rec[]) 
RETURNS TABLE (c1 BIGINT, c2 BIGINT)
AS $$
BEGIN
  RETURN QUERY
  SELECT table1.c1, sum(table2.c2)
  FROM table1
  INNER JOIN (
    SELECT u.c1, u.c2 FROM unnest(almost_a_table) u
  ) table2 ON table1.c1 = table2.c1
  GROUP BY table1.c1;
END
$$ LANGUAGE plpgsql;
```

How to use this function:

```
SELECT *
FROM my_func((
  SELECT array_agg(row(t.a, t.b)::my_rec)
  FROM some_table t
))
```

#### Using jOOQ for the above

Note, since you mentioned that you have jOOQ on your stack, this approach might be ideal also when using jOOQ, as jOOQ's code generator will generate all the boiler-plate code for you, such that you can access `my_func` from your jOOQ queries just the same. Details here:

http://www.jooq.org/doc/latest/manual/sql-building/table-expressions/table-valued-functions

Comment: Much thanks. Lukas. How can i pass static record instead of selecting from table.
Something like this:  SELECT array_agg((row(3,3),row(4,4))::my_rec) inside function call.

Comment: @UdeetSolanki: `array[row(3,3),row(4,4)]::my_rec[]`. Don't use `array_agg`

Comment: Cool. Thanks. Worked like a charm

Answer (score 1):

You can not do this in a view, but you can create a PL/pgSQL function that takes a table or view name and returns records that meet the query definition. Since the table name is not known beforehand, you have to dynamically execute the query on the table name passed in using `RETURN QUERY EXECUTE`:

```
CREATE FUNCTION aggregated_data(nm name) RETURNS TABLE (c1 integer, c2 float) AS $$
BEGIN
  RETURN QUERY EXECUTE 
   'SELECT table1.c1, sum(table2.c2) ' ||
   'FROM table1 ' ||
   'INNER JOIN ( ' ||
   '  SELECT c1, c2 FROM ' || quote_ident(nm) ||
   ') table2 ON table2.c1 = table1.c1 ' ||
   'GROUP BY table1.c1';
END; $$ LANGUAGE plpgsql STRICT;
```

Since this function returns a relation, you can - and indeed you should - use this function in the `FROM` clause of your larger query, just like you would with a view:

```
SELECT t.*, ad.c2
FROM t
JOIN aggregated_data('relation_with_c1_and_c2_columns') ad ON ad.c1 = t.id;
```